# multi-threaded code to check proxies

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm suffering with this VB.Net 2017 code which is supposed to check if Proxies working or not. Sometimes it reach to an end successfully, and sometimes the program never reach and end or take lots of time to do so, although I have specified the timeout for every webrequest to be 11000... Also, the list of working proxies always has duplicates! I don't know how that happens, althoug the original (raw) list is unique!

Could you please help? This is supposed to wait till the 99 threads finished then another 99 (or the remaining threads) kick-started.

P.S. MYWEBSITE.com works for me only and it displays the IP address of the visitor, i.e. to double check if the proxy has worked fine

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Threading

Public Class frmMain
    Dim FinalWorkingProxies As New List(Of String)()

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

        PB.Maximum = txtRawIP.Lines.Count
        PB.Value = 0

        StartCheckingIP(0)

    End Sub

    Function StartCheckingIP(ByVal num As Integer)
        For I As Integer = num To txtRawIP.Lines.Count - 1

            Dim StrIPOnly As String = txtRawIP.Lines(I)
            StrIPOnly = Trim(StrIPOnly.TrimStart("0"c)) 'remove any leading zeros

            Try
                Dim clsThreads As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf CheckIP)
                clsThreads.Start(StrIPOnly)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(I)
            End Try


            If (I > 0 And (I Mod 99 = 0)) Then Exit For

        Next

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function CheckIP(ByVal Prox As String) As Boolean
        'txtHTML.Text += vbCrLf & Prox
        'txtHTML.Refresh()

        Dim txtWebResult As String = ""
        Dim OriginalFullProx As String = Trim(Prox)
        Dim proxyObject As WebProxy = New WebProxy("http://" & OriginalFullProx & "/")
        proxyObject.BypassProxyOnLocal = True

        Prox = Prox.Substring(0, Prox.IndexOf(":"))

        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = "http://MYWEBSITE.com/testip.php"

        Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
        wrGETURL.Proxy = proxyObject
        wrGETURL.Timeout = 6000

        txtWebResult = "Dosn't work"

        Try
            Dim objStream As Stream
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream

            Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
            Dim sLine As String = ""
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine

            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
                txtWebResult = sLine
            End If
            txtWebResult = Regex.Replace(txtWebResult, “^\s+$[\r\n]*”, “”, RegexOptions.Multiline)

            If (Trim(Prox) = Trim(txtWebResult)) Then
                FinalWorkingProxies.Add(OriginalFullProx)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtWebResult = "Dosn't work"
        End Try

        If (PB.Value < PB.Maximum) Then PB.Value += 1
        PB.Refresh()

        If (PB.Value = PB.Maximum) Then
            txtFilteredIP.Clear()
            Randomize()
            Dim RRR As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 1000)) + 1
            Thread.Sleep(RRR)
            If (txtFilteredIP.Text <> "") Then Return False

            Dim str As String
            For Each str In FinalWorkingProxies
                txtFilteredIP.Text += str & vbCrLf
            Next
        ElseIf ((PB.Value - 1) > 0 And ((PB.Value - 1) Mod 99 = 0)) Then
            StartCheckingIP(PB.Value)
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub txtRawIP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRawIP.TextChanged
        lblRawIPTotal.Text = "Total: " & txtRawIP.Lines.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtFilteredIP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilteredIP.TextChanged
        lblFilteredIPTotal.Text = "Total: " & txtFilteredIP.Lines.Count

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the modified code, but it stills takes long of time to finalize long list of proxies, although I sat max concurrent connection to 2000 and timeout to 8sec. Please help. Thanks.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim FinalWorkingProxies As New List(Of String)()

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        'Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2000
        'ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True


        FinalWorkingProxies.Clear()

        PB.Maximum = txtRawIP.Lines.Count
        PB.Value = 0

        StartCheckingIP(0)

    End Sub

    Function StartCheckingIP(ByVal num As Integer)
        For I As Integer = num To txtRawIP.Lines.Count - 1

            Dim StrIPOnly As String = txtRawIP.Lines(I)
            StrIPOnly = Trim(StrIPOnly.TrimStart("0"c)) 'remove any leading zeros

            Try
                Dim clsThreads As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf CheckIP)
                clsThreads.Start(StrIPOnly)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(I)
            End Try


            If (I > 0 And (I Mod 333 = 0)) Then Exit For

        Next

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function CheckIP(ByVal Prox As String) As Boolean
        'txtHTML.Text += vbCrLf & Prox
        'txtHTML.Refresh()

        Dim txtWebResult As String = ""
        Dim OriginalFullProx As String = Trim(Prox)
        Dim proxyObject As WebProxy = New WebProxy("http://" & OriginalFullProx & "/")
        proxyObject.BypassProxyOnLocal = True

        Prox = Prox.Substring(0, Prox.IndexOf(":"))

        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = "http://MYWEBSITE.com/testip.php"

        Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
        wrGETURL.Proxy = proxyObject
        wrGETURL.Timeout = 8000

        txtWebResult = "Dosn't work"

        Try
            Dim objStream As Stream
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream

            Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
            Dim sLine As String = ""
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine

            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
                txtWebResult = sLine
            End If
            txtWebResult = Regex.Replace(txtWebResult, “^\s+$[\r\n]*”, “”, RegexOptions.Multiline)


            If (Trim(Prox) = Trim(txtWebResult)) Then
                'Now know exact country
                sURL = "http://ip-api.com/xml/" & Prox
                wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
                wrGETURL.Proxy = proxyObject
                wrGETURL.Timeout = 8000
                objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
                Dim objReader2 As New StreamReader(objStream)
                Dim FullCODEOFAPI As String = objReader2.ReadToEnd()
                Dim XMLR As XmlReader
                XMLR = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(FullCODEOFAPI))

                XMLR.ReadToFollowing("country")
                XMLR.Read()

                OriginalFullProx += "-" + XMLR.Value

                FinalWorkingProxies.Add(OriginalFullProx)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtWebResult = "Dosn't work"
        End Try

        If (PB.Value < PB.Maximum) Then UpdatePB(1)

        If (PB.Value = PB.Maximum) Then
            UpdateFilteredList(1)

        ElseIf ((PB.Value - 1) > 0 And ((PB.Value - 1) Mod 333 = 0)) Then
            StartCheckingIP(PB.Value)
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Delegate Sub UpdatePBDelegate(ByVal PBVal As Integer)

    Private Sub UpdatePB(ByVal PBVal As Integer)
        If PB.InvokeRequired Then
            PB.Invoke(New UpdatePBDelegate(AddressOf UpdatePB), New Object() {PBVal})
        Else
            PB.Value += PBVal
            PB.Refresh()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateFilteredListDelegate()

    Private Sub UpdateFilteredList(ByVal TMP As Integer)
        If txtFilteredIP.InvokeRequired Then
            txtFilteredIP.Invoke(New UpdatePBDelegate(AddressOf UpdateFilteredList), New Object() {TMP})
        Else
            txtFilteredIP.Clear()
            Dim str As String
            For Each str In FinalWorkingProxies

                txtFilteredIP.Text += str & vbCrLf
            Next
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtRawIP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRawIP.TextChanged
        lblRawIPTotal.Text = "Total: " & txtRawIP.Lines.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtFilteredIP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilteredIP.TextChanged
        lblFilteredIPTotal.Text = "Total: " & txtFilteredIP.Lines.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLoadList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadList.Click
        OFD.ShowDialog()
        If (OFD.FileName <> "") Then
            txtRawIP.Text = File.ReadAllText(OFD.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The very first issue is that you're setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False`.  If you feel the need to do that then you're probably covering up some other issue.  Get rid of that, do the proper marshaling and then we can talk properly.

Comment: Thanks dear @jmcilhinney for your quick reply. I used that because I want to access controls from within the threads, without that I cannot achieve the same. If you have a more proper way to populate controls from within threads then please advise. Many thanks.

Comment: Exactly.  Don't do that.  It's bad.  It's possible that it is the root of your other issues.  Do it properly.  If you want to access a control then marshal a method to the UI thread to do so.  If you don't do that then your code is a hack and I for one will not be spending any time helping with issues that are quite possibly the result of that hack.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have searched over the net about this issue and used a separate sub with InvokeRequired check.... the app seems working fine now!!!!!!! Thanks dear... I have another issue and I'm not sure if I can ask it here or I should open a separate post. The issue is that the form size always open in a diff size than the one I specify in the size property field. Even if I set the min and max sizes to the same predefined size, still it change during runtime... I face this problem only on my laptop that has 4K display. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: If the question you were asking here has been answered then you should mark it so.  If you answered it yourself, post an answer yourself and accept it.  You should ask any new questions in their own posts.

Comment: @jmcilhinney here is the final code, but it dosn't work as expected with large number of proxies :( ... It takes extremely long time to finish although I sat the max number of concurrent connections to 2000 and made timeout 8sec. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should not be creating `Thread` objects directly. If you want to go old school then use the `ThreadPool` class. These days though, you should be using `Task` objects.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I didn't write a code since very long time, I'm not aware even about the basic dears, so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I have searched on the web and replaced the threads with following code Task.Run(Function() CheckIP(StrIPOnly))

 but it became much worse. Very very slow.

Comment: In case anyone has a solution then please help. Thanks.